# Null Pointer Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Getting null pointer exception please help

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

    toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    NavFragment drawerFragment = (NavFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_frag);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.nav_frag, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout), toolbar);
    listEvents= new ArrayList<>();



    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    //TEST PARSE
    final TextView t =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Test");
    //query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> eventList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("Events", "Retrieved " + eventList.size() + " Events");

                for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
                    Events events = new Events();
                    events.setTitle((String) eventList.get(i).get("teststr"));
                    events.setId((String) eventList.get(i).get("id"));
                    listEvents.add(events);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    eventAdapter.setEventList(listEvents);


    eventsList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list_events);
    eventsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    eventAdapter= new EventAdapter(this);
    eventsList.setAdapter(eventAdapter);




}
```

this is the place where i get the exception .. 
logcat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   com.squaredbytes.eventlane.EventAdapter.setEventList(java.util.ArrayList)'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: Pretty sure SO gets hundreds of NPE posts a day. This will likely be closed as a dupe. Just a warning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to call a method on eventAdapter before instantiating it.

Comment: could you please explain.. thanks

Comment: Change your code as follows:
`eventAdapter= new EventAdapter(this);
 eventAdapter.setEventList(listEvents);

 eventsList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list_events);
 eventsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
 eventsList.setAdapter(eventAdapter);`